# How to identify if any child procedures get failed?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, one have master stored procedure and another are multiple child procedures​.

While calling child procedure in master if any child procedure get failed so how we can identify it?

This question asked me an interview.

Comment: (TRY CATCH) .. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the nested procedure in try catch block. In following example, if some error is thrown by SP2 upon executing SP1, the error will be captured in catch block and error message will be displayed accordingly. Refer to the article [ERROR_MESSAGE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-message-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for further details.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[SP1]
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY  
    EXEC SP2 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage; -- capture error
END CATCH
END
```